# QGIS or Postgis - How to split polylines with a point layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis, point, line, splitting

In QGIS, I would like to split the polylines in a layer loaded in the workspace with the points in another loaded layer. If a point intersects a polyline, this polyline should be transformed into two polylines...

I've read that this could be done with grass but i have no idea how to do it with layers (SHP)loaded in the QGIS workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see solutions using GRASS [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/How-to-split-a-line-using-points-tp4981464.html)

There's also another option with Spatialite. The newest version 4.0 has a [function](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.0.0.html#p14b) LinesCutAtNodes() which does what you want. You feed it a linestring geometry and a point geometry, and it returns a linestring split wherever a point exactly intersect a vertex on the line. The points have to intersect vertices on the line, so you should do snap() first to get the points to exactly intersect the line vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I do not have SQLIte to use those functions but i do use Postgis. In fact the layers i loaded in the QGIS Map Canvas are loaded from postgis. Is there any similar function in Postgis? I've seen that st_snap() exists but nothing similar to Spatialites LinesCutAtNodes()?

Comment: In PostGIS you could probably use a combination of ST_Line_Locate_Point() to find the fractional distance along your linestring for each point, then ST_Line_Interpolate_Point() to find the new node. and finally ST_AddPoint() to stick a the node into the linestring. THis would all have to go into a function with a "for each" loop.

Answer (score 2):

For PostGIS [ST_Split](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html) is the maching function.
You can use [ST_Snap](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html) to add some tolerance into the calculation